# Why do we use <script "inline" ..> tag while using Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone tell me why "in-line" attribute used inside the  tag,
For example:

```
<script inline type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Without this attribute, the JS does not load in the page

Comment: Does that attribute even exist? *starts rummaging through W3C specs*

Comment: I have never used "inline" and my javascript files load without problems.

Comment: I guess the answer to your question would be: Because the author didn't know better. *"Without this attribute, the JS does not load in the page"* That's hard to believe. Are you using any special server side technology that could be responsible for the `inline` attribute?

Comment: Or JavaScript which looks for it?

Comment: You need to show a larger piece of code than that to back up your claim that the javascript doesn't load without ti.

Answer (score 2):

The 'inline' property does not exist for the script tag.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes)

Nor does it exist in the list of [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)

When people say "inline javascript" they're talking about using script tags to put javascript on the page

```
<script>
    alert('hello world!!!');
</script>
```

Or just into an html tag

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">click here!</a>
```

as opposed to in a separate file.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```